# how to give padding on top for Scrollbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

*I've attempted various methods to apply top padding to the scrollbar, but I haven't been successful.*
Thanks in advance..

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyScrollableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScrollableWidgetState createState() => _MyScrollableWidgetState();
}

class _MyScrollableWidgetState extends State<MyScrollableWidget> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  double _opacity = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        // Add your animation logic here based on scroll offset
        _opacity = _scrollController.offset > 100 ? 0.0 : 1.0;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hey there'),
      ),
      body: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData(
            thumbColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.red)
          )
        ),
        child: Scrollbar(
          
         // controller: _scrollController,
          isAlwaysShown: true,
          child: ListView.builder(
            //controller: _scrollController,
            itemCount: 100,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('Item $index'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: _opacity,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Your FAB logic here
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate your various attempted methods and how they failed.

Answer (score 0):

Add `mainAxisMargin` in `ScrollbarThemeData` to get the padding above scrollbar.

```
      const ScrollbarThemeData(
        thumbColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.red),
        mainAxisMargin: 40,
      ),
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: It isn't functioning as intended; in addition, it's applying padding to the bottom. I specifically desire top padding without any padding at the bottom..